# Starting a resque task within your rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

For development purposes, it is quite convenient to have my resque workers start/stop with my Rails app, but every example I find shows how to run a worker with a rake task.

So, here's what I've done so far, and it I've seen jobs be taken off the queue and processed successfully.  But it's a completely uninformed attempt.  Are there any pitfalls to this approach, or could it be done better?  However, I have encountered one serious problem related to ActiveRecord.  I'm pretty sure the ralis app and the worker are both using the same activerecord connection at times.  I need to figure that out, clearly.

I ripped off the guts of resques' worker task code, and put it in my config/initializer/resque.rb, like shown below.  I did bother to pre-populate the QUEUES env variable if not set, so that developers don't have to type as much with our rails app.

```
Resque.redis = Rails.application.config.redis_host


if !$rails_rake_task && Rails.env == 'development'

  # pre-populate QUEUES env var with '*' if not set
  ENV['QUEUES'] ||= '*'

  Thread.new do
    # from: https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/1-x-stable/lib/resque/tasks.rb
    queues = (ENV['QUEUES'] || ENV['QUEUE']).to_s.split(',')

    begin
      worker = Resque::Worker.new(*queues)
      if ENV['LOGGING'] || ENV['VERBOSE']
        worker.verbose = ENV['LOGGING'] || ENV['VERBOSE']
      end
      if ENV['VVERBOSE']
        worker.very_verbose = ENV['VVERBOSE']
      end
      worker.term_timeout = ENV['RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT'] || 4.0
      worker.term_child = ENV['TERM_CHILD']
      worker.run_at_exit_hooks = ENV['RUN_AT_EXIT_HOOKS']
    rescue Resque::NoQueueError
      abort "set QUEUE env var, e.g. $ QUEUE=critical,high rake resque:work"
    end

    if ENV['BACKGROUND']
      unless Process.respond_to?('daemon')
        abort "env var BACKGROUND is set, which requires ruby >= 1.9"
      end
      Process.daemon(true, true)
    end

    if ENV['PIDFILE']
      File.open(ENV['PIDFILE'], 'w') { |f| f << worker.pid }
    end

    worker.log "Starting worker #{worker}"

    worker.work(ENV['INTERVAL'] || 5) # interval, will block
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding an environment variable in Raquefile

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best I've come up with that seems to have no issue is running a rake task using `system()` in a thread. I was just hoping to avoid creating a whole new process.

```
Resque.redis = Rails.application.config.redis_host

if !$rails_rake_task && Rails.env == 'development'

  Thread.new do
    system("QUEUE='*'bundle exec rake environment resque:work")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is set `Resque.inline = true` in your development.rb file.  This is a bad idea generally speaking - but if you're trying to debug Resque jobs, or run tests around them, it can be a helpful setting.  Basically, it will run Resque in the same process as your Rails application, pausing the Rails app while the job runs.